# Difference between tuples in list of tuples

Tags: python, tuples

In Python, I have a list of tuples, that is:

```
list_tup = [('123', 'A'), ('123', 'B')]
```

If I want to find out if there is, for example, the tuple `('123', 'A')`, I just write:

```
('123', 'A') in list_tup
=> True
```

But what if I'd like to know if there's anything different from `('123', 'B')` in that list of tuples, where the only different element is the second one `('B')`? Is it possible?

For example, I want to know if in `list_tup` there is something different from ('123', 'B').

Comment: Not quite sure what you want, but call np.unique on list_tup?

Comment: Can you show an example? You want to return all tuples that have 123 but not B?

Comment: `any(tup[0] == '123' and tup[1] != 'B' for tup in list_tup)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
any(tup for tup in list_tup if tup[0] == '123' and tup[1] != 'B')
```

Basically filters the list of tuples to those that have `'123'` as the first value and not `'B'` as the second value, and returns True if there are any (haha).

But you can also modify this to get the list of all tuples that match the criteria by switching [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-list).

Comment: that's correct, saw your last line later. for that filter would be better choice. But that can be opinion based ;)